# Java Jpa - How to perform a query with jpa with repeated data

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I need to form a query between two related tables to get all the records that are not related and those that are also related.

Person table has @OneToMany with company table.

Each record of the person, may or may not be associated with many companies, for example, in the person table a record has five associated records in the company table, I need to obtain this record five times repeated by assigning it the data from the company table.
The problem I have is that I only get one record of the person and the property, @OneToMany List  of the person, has the other records associated with it.

I want to obtain, as in the example, five records of the person repeated each one associated with a different company and also the people who are not associated with any company

```
Person              Company     
ID  Name            ID      Name         TableAID
1   Name one        1   Name tableB1        1
2   Name two        2   Name tableB2        1
3   Name three      3   Name tableB3        1
4   Name four       4   Name tableB4        2
5   Name five       5   Name tableB5        3
```

List personList = "select person from Person person ...."

```
       ID
```

**Person_1** : id-1 Name one / Company (1)
**Person_1** : id-1 Name one / Company (2)
**Person_1** : id-1 Name one / Company (3)
**Person_2** : id-2 Name two/ Company (4)
**Person_3** : id-3 Name three / Company (5)
**Person_4** : id-4 Name four/ Company (null)
**Person_5** : id-5 Name five/ Company (null)

**Solution for me:**
Instead of collecting the entities as such I have had to collect a list of objects and parse the values ​​I need by hand.

Before:
List personList = query.getResultList();

After:
List<Object[]> personList = query.getResultList();

Each array is the values ​​that I am returning from the query, example:

```
Select person, company from Person person left join Company company on 
company.person = person.company


Object[] objectOne = [person, company];
Object[] objectTwo = [person, company];
```

For each value of the array I cast the same entity, example:

```
Person person = (Person) objectOne[0];
Company company = (Company) objectOne[1];
```

Comment: I don't know. Why would you force your database to send you redundant data, when JPA and its @OneToMany relation was exactly invented for this scenario. Just query for persons. Each person.getCompanies() will then lazily query for those companies. Will produce more queries, but less traffic.

Comment: i need to do it like this because i am going to display it in html table like this and i need to paginate the results. If I only obtain all the records from the person table, the pagination is not done correctly and some records would be lost and would not be displayed in the html table

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you've mapped the Person and Company entities, or their relationship, but for every relationship, there is an inverse side of things. Try looking at this as a Company query, not a person query.

"Select person, company From Company company join company.people person where ..."

This will return a List<Object[]> where each row is represented as an object array where position 0 is the person, and position 1 is the company.

Same thing going the other way if you only have the person-> company relationship mapped:

"Select person, company From Person person join person.companies company where ..."

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I update de question, i found a possible solution, it works for me.